# Why is my background image is zoomed in?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set a background image which is 1920*1080, and from some reason the picture is being zoomed in and also being cropped.

In addition, I would like to know if there's a possibility to set the `<navbar>` to not cover the top part of the background. Is there any chance of separating it?

**This is the background settings on my CSS File**:

```
body {
  background: url(images/back.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

body,
html {
  font-family: 'Caveat Brush', cursive;
  color: white;
}
```

This is how the [image looks like on my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqQzJ.jpg):

Thank you.

Comment: what if you try `height: 1920; width: 1080px;`?

Comment: still the same no change

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using background-size: cover;
this will scale the background image to fit the width and hight of the html element it is in, while stretching and / or croping the image.
Considering the navbar:
if you have the navbar in your html and it has a given height for example 50px just add

```
body { 
    padding-top: 50px;
    background-position: top 50px center;
}
```

to your css

Comment: adding margin-top to body won't fix it..since navbar will be inside the body. You can use padding instead and say background-position: top 50px center.

Comment: so what code should i write instead of the background-size: cover

Comment: you can try background-size: contain; but I usually go with cover it is the most responsive option

Comment: unfortunately no change is seen :\

Comment: can you create a plucker?

Comment: I'm afftaid to say that I don't know what is plucker

Comment: http://codepen.io/pen/ here you can recreate your problem and share it with us. -> we can try and fix it more easily

Answer (score 0):

After making some changes according your suggestions, the navbar itself is getting lower with the paddding (Image will be attached).

the code of the html is that:

```
    </head>
    <body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Eyal Younger </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HTML COURSE</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

the css code:

```
body { 

    padding-top: 50px;
    background-position: top 50px center;   
    background: url(images/back.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: height: 1920 width: 1080px;

}

body,
html {

    font-family: 'Caveat Brush', cursive;
    color:white;    
}

h1 {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 5em;

}

h3 {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;


}

#mainimg {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 8px double red;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 6px #353232;

}



.content {
    padding: 6%;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.9),
                 0px 8px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                 0px 18px 23px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);


}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNcHs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the full background image

```
body{
margin: 0;
background:url('images/back.jpg') no-repeat fixed 0 -300px;
background-size:100%;
```

Comment: Wow that definitly seperates the navbar from the background, thank you for that!
But is there anything to keep the real proportions for the background image?

Comment: I'm also a beginner so I'm not completely sure, not sure if this is what you are looking for but you can move the image along the x and y axis to get it looking the way you want(I've edited the post above)  If i could maybe see  a screenshot of the page for I can get a better idea of whats going on

Comment: Here is a link to example how it looks like on my browser and how it changes the proportion of my background image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y87Q.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This is how it zooms my background image
[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y87Q.jpg)